# I can't take only a part of string

Tags: java

I have basic knowledge about C and java.
I have to make a java project to read an html files in this form

The file is in HTML and I want same info inside the `<pre>` tag.  The file content is like this:

```
<html>
<pre>


Extraction of Roots by Repeated Subtractions for Digital Computers<-- i wand to take this line the title

CACM December, 1958

Sugai, I. <--- and this line

CA581202 JB March 22, 1978  8:29 PM

2   5   2
2   5   2
2   5   2

</pre>
</html>
```

I want to take only the title and the writers if the file has them.

I wrote this code but I could not take the writers.  I got useless information

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Element link;
String text,str,name,title,name2=null; 
Document doc;
File in = new File("path");
doc = Jsoup.parse(in, null);
link = doc.select("pre").first();
text = doc.body().text();
String []lines = text.split("[\r\n]+");
for (String string : lines) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(string);
}   
str = builder.toString();
String[] strings = str.split(",");
title=strings[0];
name=strings[2];
```

Comment: can you describe exactly what you get ? and what you want ? also your code seems a bit strange because you say you want stuff in the "pre" tag but you are parsing the body with text.split() and not the link.

Comment: Tell us the exact problem you have: Are you not able to get the text between `<pre></pre>`? Or you can get it but you cannot correctly process the text to get the line you want?  Be specific for your question so that people can help

Comment: i take it the first is the  
Preliminary Report-International Algebraic Language CACM Decemb
 A. J. Samelson
but i take and CACM Decemb
in the second take and the numbers because the have not a writer and continues after the third return them anything except Title and authors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that all of your files have the same format you could do this.  after running getTxt you could just access the 3rd and fifth element in the array.  Or you could parse the file.  Catch everything between pre> and the date.  Then catch what between the data and some form of CA581202 JB March 22, 1978  8:29 PM.

```
static public ArrayList<String> getTxt(String urlString){
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Access the page
    try {
        // Create a URL for the desired page
        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(str);
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        }
        in.close();             
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }          
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so , i use the code and the split() and removeAll() and is work just fine All of thenks :)

Comment: Thank you i try this code and put the replaceAll() and spilt() and works fine